# WPF: how to invoke a method in a separate thread with a delay time

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, c#-4.0, dispatcher

I have a `TextBox` that user can enter search-term in it. Its bind to `string Term` property in my `view-model`. And I want to do a search query when its content changed. But I want to do the query in a separate thread with a **delay**.

e.g. when user type a letter, I want to wait for **0.3 second**, and if user change the input within this time (0.3 second), the timer **resets and starts** again. Otherwise, I start a new thread and do the search query. While query is executing, if user change the term again, abort prev query and start again.

I know how to do this in windows-forms with threading and `Timer` class. But I'm new to `WPF` and I'm searching if there is a way specified for WPF threading functionality (or may be a way with a better performance).

Have you any idea? Can you help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`DispatcherTimer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatchertimer.aspx). On each keypress, stop the timer if it's already running, then start it. I *believe* (and you should check this!) that that will reset it.

If it fires, you then take the current value in the textbox and start performing the operation in a separate thread (e.g. using `Task.Factory.StartNew`, if you're using .NET 4, or `BackgroundWorker`, or just creating a new thread).

Basically that separates the "new thread" part from the "do I really want to do something" part, keeping everything on the UI thread until the point where you've decided you really *do* want to do something (and you know the value you want to use).

Comment: Well, you are **Jon Skeet** and I can't understand what are you talking about!!! :D I'm so new to `WPF` and I have just 187 point at SO. Your solution seems better than Robaticus's one, but I need some codes to understand it :D I'm thinking, I should I have **one** thread (instead of having a new one on each query, it seems a better performance) and just run or abort it. Is it true? Also it's my pleasure to talking with you. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @king.net: You don't want to abort threads, but you could always ignore the results if the input has changed. Read up on `DispatcherTimer` for that part of things, and then tackle the threading separately.

Comment: OK you're right. I read about <a href="http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms615945.aspx">DispatcherTimer</a> and I understand what are you talking about just now. But just one question before start coding: Can I stop `DispatcherTimer` from its `CallBack`?

Comment: @king.net: To stop further "ticks"? Absolutely.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works. Also thank you for `DispatcherTimer` that I learn new. However, there is a scenario that may cause a logical error: 1: term changed, 2: `timer.stop()` and `timer.start()` 3: for 0.3s user not changes the term so 4: query begins invoking, 5: when query completed I stop the timer again, but 6: invoking query take a while (for example 2s), 7: while query is invoking, user changes the term, 8: `timer.stop()` occurs (and also `timer.start()` after it), but just timer stoped, and query is running! How can I abort it? have you any idea please?

Comment: I had a BackgrouWorker with a delay in worker but I tested this approach and like it better.  I will post the full answer but please give the check mark to Jon Skeet.

Comment: @king.net: Once you've issued the query, you don't need the timer at all (unless the user types another character). But you wouldn't normally abort the query - you'd just ignore the results. Of course if your query *does* support cancellation, that's great - but we'd need to know more about the search to know how to help you on that front.

Comment: +Jon Skeet OK I understand completely. Thank you again.

Comment: @JonSkeet I do part one. But there is another problem. Can you take a look at completion please: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10534290/gui-froze-while-dispatcher-begininvoke-or-task-startnew

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look into the [Reactive Extensions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg577609) from Microsoft.  Rx provides a way to aggregate these types of events into a single event, once a certain delay has passed.

Phil Haack (formerly of Microsoft) had a good article on his [blog](http://haacked.com/archive/2012/04/09/reactive-extensions-sample.aspx) where he talks about the throttling capability.

Answer (score 0):

This just builds on what Jon Skeets said.  Give the check mark to him. The `.stop()` appears to reset the `timer`.

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    backgroundWorker1 = new BackgroundWorker();
    backgroundWorker1.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
    backgroundWorker1.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
    backgroundWorker1.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(backgroundWorker1_DoWork);
    backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted);
    backgroundWorker1.ProgressChanged += new ProgressChangedEventHandler(backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged);

    dispatcherTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(dispatcherTimer_Tick);
    dispatcherTimer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 4);
}

public string Input
{
    get { return input; }
    set
    {
        if (value == input) return;
        value = value.Trim();
        input = value;
        NotifyPropertyChanged("Input");

        if (backgroundWorker1.IsBusy) backgroundWorker1.CancelAsync();
        dispatcherTimer.Stop();                
        dispatcherTimer.Start();
    }
 }

private void dispatcherTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    dispatcherTimer.Stop();
    if (!backgroundWorker1.IsBusy)
    {
        backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync(Input);
    }
}
```

Comment: As John said, it seems if we have a query with cancellation support, `BackgroundWorker` is not necessary. However thank you

Comment: In my case it is not a query.

Comment: I do part one. But there is another problem. Can you take a look at completion please: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10534290/gui-froze-while-dispatcher-begininvoke-or-task-startnew